# Import error with GeoPandas in Jupyter Notebook on OSX10.11.6

Tags: import, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

When importing geopandas into my Jupyter Notebook, it throws the following error.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/_datadir.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib
```

I have installed geopandas through a pip install from the command line.
My machine runs OSX 10.11.6 (and can't upgrade).

I have also tried uninstalling the pip install and installing through conda instead. Importing geopandas in my JN then throws the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'geopandas._compat' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by restarting Jupyter Notebooks.